# php login script, give an error message if the name or password is incorrect

Tags: php, authentication

How do I change this script, which he displays an error message if the name or password is incorrect?
I'm new here in, Can someone explain it to me

```
<?php
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=md5($_POST['password']);
    $login=$_POST['login'];
    if(isset($login)){

        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "Tech112!", "ripper");
        if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli->connect_error;
        }
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM login where LOWER(`username`) = ? and password = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', strtolower($username), $password);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();  
        $name = $row['name_login'];
        $user = $row['username'];
        $pass = $row['password'];
        $rank = $row['type_login'];
        if($user==$username && $pass=$password){
            session_start();
            if($rank=="2"){
                $_SESSION['mysesi']=$user;
                $_SESSION['rank']=$rank;
                echo "<script>window.location.assign('index.php')</script>";
                } else if($rank=="1"){
                $_SESSION['mysesi']=$user;
                $_SESSION['rank']=$rank;
                echo "<script>window.location.assign('index.php')</script>";
            } 

        }
    } 
?>
```

Tom Lammers

Comment: Well, your SQL statement gets a row where LOGIN & PASS match to user entry. If the sql statement returns a line, then you can be sure that there is a record that match user and pass in database. At that moment, you have to handle return data. IF NOT, then display error message... try something like : if(count==1) ...

Comment: It's a very bad idea to store passwords in plain text. Please consider hashing the passwords.

Comment: I don't store the passwords in plain text??

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an else statement, like so

```
 if($user==$username && $pass=$password){
        session_start();
        if($rank=="2"){
            $_SESSION['mysesi']=$user;
            $_SESSION['rank']=$rank;
            echo "<script>window.location.assign('index.php')</script>";
            } else if($rank=="1"){
            $_SESSION['mysesi']=$user;
            $_SESSION['rank']=$rank;
            echo "<script>window.location.assign('index.php')</script>";

    }
    else { 
        echo "Invalid login";
    }
```

This will output an error message only, you'll need to format that code to something more useful.

I would also count the rows, to ensure you're actually getting something back from the MySQL, like so.

```
if($result->num_rows == 1) {
     if($user==$username && $pass=$password){    
            session_start();
            if($rank=="2"){
                $_SESSION['mysesi']=$user;
                $_SESSION['rank']=$rank;
                echo "<script>window.location.assign('index.php')</script>";
                } else if($rank=="1"){
                $_SESSION['mysesi']=$user;
                $_SESSION['rank']=$rank;
                echo "<script>window.location.assign('index.php')</script>";

        }
        else { 
            echo "Invalid login - Username and passwords do not match";
        }
}
else {
    echo "Invalid Login - Single entry not returned";
}
```

I would also do a major security review on your code, you should never be storing passwords in plain text format.